# What is wrong with this struct X in C++ code?

Tags: c++, class, struct

I got this question as a homework assignment.
It compiled and ran as expected and yet I'm supposed to find something wrong with it, though nothing to do with the const.

I know this is a struct so my variables are all public - that is not the problem. I thought perhaps it is related to the "new" used in the constructor.
I would love to hear your thoughts.

```
struct X
{
    explicit X(int);
    ~X();
    void Foo();
    void Bar() const;

    int m_a;
    int *m_p;
};

X::X(int a_): m_a(a_), m_p(new int(a_)){}
X::~X()
{
    delete m_p;
    m_p = NULL;
}

void X::Foo()
{
    ++m_a;
    --(*m_p);
}

void X::Bar() const
{
    std::cout<<m_a<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<*m_p<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<m_p<<std::endl;
}

void Fifi(const X& x_)
{
    x_.Bar();
}

int main (void)
{
    X x1(1);
    x1.Foo();
    Fifi(x1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "wrong"? That's a pretty open-ended term. Have you tried exercising the struct in different ways other than that contrived case in `main`?

Comment: Try changing the program to pass `X` by value to `Fifi`. It should become apparent once you run it.

Comment: Think what would happen if you coppied an object of type X. The copy constructor generated by compiler would copy the m_p pointer and then two X objects would use the same copy of dynamically allocated int. Then when destructors are called that single int would get destructed twice.

Comment: @navyblue - Spilling *all* the beans robs the the OP from the chance to work it out, and learn.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry, I didn't think about it this way.

Comment: Got it! thank you so much! So to make it right I need to write my own copy constructor that does not copy the same pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Your class violates [the rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Exactly as written it doesn't do anything bad, but seemingly harmless constructs involving `X` may cause mysterious errors (due to various forms of undefined behaviour).

```
X a(1), b = a;
```

On my machine the above line causes

> ```
> *** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000dfec20 ***
> ```