# Trying to delete a dynamically allocated object causes a run-time crash

Tags: c++, oop, memory, optimization, runtime-error

I'm working on optimizing my current CLI project. When looking through the code and debugging I've noticed that I haven't released some dynamically allocated memory in a class. Here's how my code looks:

"Coordinates.h"

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

#define LENGTH 40
#define WIDTH 15

struct Coordinate
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
};
```

"Laser.h"

```
#pragma once
#include "Coordinates.h"

class Laser
{
private:
    Coordinate* initCoord;
    char icon;

public:
    Laser(int x, int y);
    char getIcon() const;
    Coordinate* getCoord();
    void move();
};
```

"Laser.cpp"

```
#include "Laser.h"

Laser::Laser(int x, int y)
{
    initCoord = new Coordinate;
    initCoord->x = x; 
    initCoord->y = y;
    icon = '~';
}

char Laser::getIcon() const { return icon; }
Coordinate* Laser::getCoord() { return initCoord; }

void Laser::move()
{
    ++initCoord->x;
}
```

I've tried adding a destructor (declaring it in the header file first of course) which clears up the memory allocated for `initCoord` which looked something like this:

```
Laser::~Laser()
{
    if(initCoord != nullpr) delete initCoord;
}
```

After adding that it caused a run-time error. "ProgramName.exe has stopped working..." Objects of this class are stored in a simple vector which gets cleared at one time of the program. The problem is that the crash happens before it even reaches the `lasers.clear()` line. I honestly have no idea why this crash is happening and would appreciate some help. Thank you! :)

Comment: You are violating the Rule of Three/Five.

Comment: I'm curious why you even are dynamically allocating a `struct` with only 2 `int` members. Just storing it as a "normal" member should be better in this case. (And if you really need to have a pointer, using a smart pointer is pretty much always going to be a better solution)

Comment: I'm not sure but doesn't that code "++initCoord->x" change your pointer instead of "x" field?

Comment: @ElChupacabra Nope, it doesn't. Operator precedence is weird sometimes... :)

Comment: Because of that weirdness I prefer to use "too many" brackets ;)

Comment: I bet this is because of the default copy constructor being invoked and you end up calling `delete` on the same `initCoord` pointer twice. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866613/what-is-wrong-with-this-struct-x-in-c-code) which is very similar.

Comment: @UnholySheep I used it as a pointer since there is a lot of "coordinate" copying in the rest of my program. As far as I know copying takes a little bit more memory than working through pointers.

Comment: That sounds like a case of "premature optimization" - did you profile to see the actual difference between copying and using a pointer (and determine that it is indeed a bottleneck)? There's much more to it than just "more memory" (and in fact using a pointer might degrade performance in your code) and on many systems/compilers a pointer might take up just as much space as 2 `int` variables (example: https://ideone.com/IPzz1n)

Comment: Okay. I'll study through the rules of three and five and do some tests whether I should use a pointer or a simple object. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider this code

```
int main() {
    Laser one(0,0);
    {
      Laser two = one;
      cout << two.getCoord()->x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What do you expect to be written?

"0"

which mean that the coordinate points to the same structure as `one` which again means that when the first `}` happens and `two` gets destroyed `one` doesn't have a valid coordinate any more.

When you have a pointer member you need to either disable copying/assigning or implement them.

In this case you could also have been rescued if you had used a std::unique_ptr instead of the raw pointer (which also saves you the delete).

Comment: Thanks or the explanation! I switched to shared_ptr as I do need to return it.